# Handling NAs of sentiments

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I have run sentiment analysis on a data frame of about 500,000 tweets using the "afinn" package. I noticed that many of the tweets have a sentiment of NA since there were no words from the afinn that were in the tweets.

the 500,000 tweets come from 500 different users, and I want to find the average sentiment of the tweet they send. Would the proper methodology to replace the NAs with 0s and then calculate the average sentiment, or should I omit the NA tweets from the calculation.

Thanks!

Comment: That would be two possible strategies. You could also collate tweets to create user-weeks or user-months, each containing all tweets from a longer time span. That takes care of most missings. Or you could extend the dictionary by adding more synonyms and different spelling. Or you try to identify new positive and negative words from the tweets already classified and add them to the dictionary. There is a lot you can do to get better sentiment scores.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the NAs to zero, the justification being that if the tweet had no positive/negative sentiment words in it then it was a neutral tweet.

If a person had 9 positive tweets averaging 0.50, 1 negative of -0.50, and zero neutral tweets, that is average of +0.40, indicating if you randomly sample one of their tweets it will most likely have positive sentiment.

Compare that to someone with the same 9 and 1 positive/negative tweets, but 40 neutral tweets. The average is +0.01. That more closely matches the expectation that randomly sampling one of their tweets it will have little sentiment.